# Mysql: applying conditions on multiple records

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table to store product variants option values (eg: colour, size, weight, the height of product variants). It contains the following data.

[image]

I have a filter option on the frontend, where users can select filter options such as colour, size, weight, height etc and I need to show product variants based on the filter values.

In the above example: option_id = 110 means size. option_id = 109 means color. Suppose a user-selected size = 31 (XL) and colour = 27 (Red),

> I have to find a product_variant_id where option_id = '110' AND
>   option_value_id = 31  AND  option_id = '109' AND option_value_id = 27.
>   (result should be records with ids 266 and 267)

There is only one such product_variant_id that is 140.

I tried

> SELECT * FROM product_variant_option_values WHERE (option_id = '110'
>   AND option_value_id = 31) OR  (option_id = '109' AND option_value_id =
>   27)

but it's not returning what I want, the above query returns

[image]

Comment: What returns your statement?

Comment: question updated, query result added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after seeing the result you are getting right now.
If I understand correctly, you want `product_variant_id` that has exactly the two conditions you mentioned.
So one option for a query could be:

```
SELECT product_variant_id
FROM product_variant_option_values 
WHERE (option_id = '110' AND option_value_id = 31) OR (option_id = '109' AND option_value_id = 27)
GROUP BY product_variant_id
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

Which means, that you count the number of rows returned per each `product_variant_id` and only return the one that has 2 rows. Which means got the two conditions.

Comment: This is what I tried,  but I should get only 140, see the result if this query in the question.

Comment: Sorry for changing the answer, after seeing your update, I realized what happened.

Comment: `WHERE (option_id, option_value_id) IN (('110', 31), ('109', 27))` is more clear and shorter.

Comment: @Akina that returns wrong results, the result should be the records with product_variant_id = 140. Your query returns multiple records

Comment: @Joyal My query? I only shows the replacement for one line in answer code - and it CANNOT alter the output. You make a mistake somewhere in replacement. Maybe you have deleted the rest 2 lines?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you can do is to add a `COUNT()` operation to see if both of the filter condition are met. Something like below:

```
SELECT   product_variant_id,COUNT(*) cnt 
FROM     product_variant_option_values 
WHERE    (option_id = '110' AND option_value_id = 31) 
  OR     (option_id = '109' AND option_value_id = 27)
GROUP BY product_variant_id
HAVING   cnt >= 2;
```

Grouped by `product_variant_id` whereby the result of `COUNT()` is 2 or more; of if the filter condition is always going to be 2 then just `HAVING cnt=2` should suffice. This query can similarly be written this way:

```
SELECT   product_variant_id,COUNT(*) cnt 
FROM     product_variant_option_values 
WHERE    option_id in ('110','109') 
  AND    option_value_id IN (27,31)
GROUP BY product_variant_id
HAVING   cnt >= 2;
```

Fiddle example : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9kKmyHsSAMNk4BBPDWLHFh/3